# How to handle IOExceptions in OkHttp Interceptor in Android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2, okhttp

I have a custom Interceptor to attach API key to the ever API request. Here is the code:

```html
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  private final ProfileDbDataSource profileDbRepository;

  @Inject public HeaderInterceptor(ProfileDbDataSource profileDbRepository) {
    this.profileDbRepository = profileDbRepository;
  }

  @NonNull @Override public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    if (!chain.request().url().toString().contains(Constants.GET_API_KEY)) {
      Request.Builder requestBuilder = attachApiKeyAsQueryParam(chain);
      return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    }
    return chain.proceed(chain.request());
  }

  private Request.Builder attachApiKeyAsQueryParam(Chain chain) {
    String apiKey = profileDbRepository.getLoggedInProfile().blockingGet().getApiKey();
    Request original = chain.request();
    HttpUrl originalHttpUrl = original.url();
    HttpUrl url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
      .addQueryParameter(Constants.USER_API_KEY, apiKey)
      .build();
    return original.newBuilder().url(url);
  }
}
```

I am seeing a few crashes happening at line `return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());` and all of those exception are subclasses of `IOException`.

I have seen `SocketTimeoutException`, `UnknownHostException` and `ConnectException`.

Here is one stack-trace:

```html
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: 
  at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError (RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMapSingle$FlatMapSingleObserver.innerError (ObservableFlatMapSingle.java:204)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFlatMapSingle$FlatMapSingleObserver$InnerObserver.onError (ObservableFlatMapSingle.java:289)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback.onError (SingleFlatMap.java:90)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onError (SingleSubscribeOn.java:73)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle$SingleElementObserver.onError (ObservableSingleSingle.java:93)
  at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onError (BodyObservable.java:72)
  at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual (CallExecuteObservable.java:59)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:12284)
  at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual (BodyObservable.java:34)
  at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe (Observable.java:12284)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual (ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
  at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe (Single.java:3666)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run (SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
  at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run (Scheduler.java:608)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run (ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call (ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 
  at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException (Http2Stream.kt:677)
  at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut (Http2Stream.kt:686)
  at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders (Http2Stream.kt:143)
  at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders (Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders (Exchange.kt:106)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept (CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
  at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept (HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:221)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
  at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
  at com.anstar.data.core.HeaderInterceptor.intercept (HeaderInterceptor.java:24)
  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp (RealCall.kt:201)
  at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute (RealCall.kt:154)
  at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute (OkHttpCall.java:204)
  at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual (CallExecuteObservable.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with your Interceptor, but rather with how you're consuming the Rx streams of your network requests. IOExceptions are usually expected errors and you should be ready to catch and handle them when doing I/O.
To do this with an Rx Observable, pass an error handler for the `onError` parameter when calling `subscribe`:

```
apiClient.request()
    .subscribe(
        /* onNext */ (response) -> /* handle response */,
        /* onError */ (error) -> /* handle error */
    )
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that you are right, but the strange thing is that I do not have any RxJava chain without onError(), since I have RxLint for that. I have a few Observable.merges and .zip(). Could be that a reason? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Then I'm not sure... are you possibly rethrowing Exceptions or using Exceptions.propagate() in an onError callback somewhere? 
merge() and zip() shouldn't be relevant in this case. If you can't find anything, I would try and track down which of your network calls exactly are causing the crashes and check and see if there's something wrong with them. Check this out starters: https://rongi.github.io/kotlin-blog/rxjava/2017/09/25/breadcrumbs-rxjava-error-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

```html
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  private final ProfileDbDataSource profileDbRepository;

  @Inject public HeaderInterceptor(ProfileDbDataSource profileDbRepository) {
    this.profileDbRepository = profileDbRepository;
  }

  @NonNull @Override public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    if (!chain.request().url().toString().contains(Constants.GET_API_KEY)) {
      Request.Builder requestBuilder = attachApiKeyAsQueryParam(chain);
      return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    }
    return chain.proceed(chain.request());
  }

  private Request.Builder attachApiKeyAsQueryParam(Chain chain) {
    String apiKey = profileDbRepository.getLoggedInProfile().blockingGet().getApiKey();
    Request original = chain.request();
    HttpUrl originalHttpUrl = original.url();
    HttpUrl url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
      .addQueryParameter(Constants.USER_API_KEY, apiKey)
      .build();
    return original.newBuilder().url(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).